# Wordpress how to add httponly and secure flag to all SETCOOKIE() function?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, cookies, php-ini

I am new to wordpress. In few plugin's code, some of the setcookie() functions has HTTPOnly and Secure flag already SET and some of the setcookie() functions are without HTTPOnly or secure flag in a code.

How can I set all setcookie() functions with HTTPonly and Secure flag, No matter HTTPOnly or Secure flag is set or not.

If I apply code for setting above flags to TRUE either in .htaccess, or use ini_set() in index.php or changes in Apache configuration, Will this affect my existing Wordpress working?

Or anyone has better solution?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible to pre-set HTTPOnly for any cookie - it is possible to set it for session cookies though.

Take a look at [PHP: SetCookie documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

For Secure bit, your site needs to run also over SSL. For HTTPOnly - in case any scripts depend on values from these cookies, HTTPOnly cookies cannot be read by JS.

You could write your own setSecureCookie() function which internally calls setcookie() ... but thats a complete code rewrite.

Comment: Thanks, Earlier my site has few SSL pages. Now to enhance security all pages are under SSL layer. My problem is that instead of find and replace setcookie function without secure or httponly, Is there any way that by setting SSL and HTTPonly flag to TRUE from one place?

Comment: I am not sure if its even possible for regular cookies. It is possible for session cookies though.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention session cookie. I am thinking of setting session.cookie_httponly and session.cookie_secure to TRUE in php.ini

Comment: session.cookie_httponly - yes please turn it on. Secure bit works for you only and only if your site is 100% SSL-enabled.

Comment: Thanks...will try it directly on production :-0

Comment: WordPress doesn't use php's session cookies, and you should not try to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possibility. It depends on various plugins and other code setting their cookies in their init hooks and not later. It's possible to intercept and fix them before they get sent.

Write a hook function for the [wp_loaded](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_loaded/) hook, and install it with a large priority, so it runs after other functions on that hook.

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'add_httponly_to_my_cookies', 9999, 0 );
```

Then, in the hook function, use php's header manipulation. This may work for you, but you should test it carefully before putting it into production.

The [header()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function's second argument lets us replace a header rather than add a new one.

```php
public function add_httponly_to_my_cookies() {
  if ( headers_sent() ) {
    /* darn! too late! cookies already sent. */
    return;
  }
  foreach ( headers_list() as $header ) {
    if ( 0 === stripos( $header, 'Set-Cookie:' ) ) {
      /* this header is a cookie! */
      if ( false === stripos( $header, 'HttpOnly' ) ) {
        /* no HttpOnly item, append it */
        $header .= '; HttpOnly';
        /* replace the cookie in the list of headers */
        header( $header, true );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This php code needs to go into a plugin or maybe a [code snippet](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/).